# Java - While loop still running outside of the conditions set?

Tags: java, loops

I'm running a gambling simulation and I can't figure out why the End Bank is sometimes below zero or above 250. I included a for loop **right after the while loop** which repeats the simulation 100 times.
Keep in mind my variables read from a text file. And the while loop only runs if the gambler has over 0 dollars and below 250, yet the end bank is sometime above or below.

- Gambler starts with 50, and stops at $0, or $250.
- While loop only runs if the gambler has above $0 or below $250.
- For loop right after While loop repeats entire simulation 100 times.
- Part 2 is currently inactive, so don't worry about it.

Any ideas?
Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class GamblersRuin {

        public static int bank;
        public static int goal;
        public static int beta;
        public static double prob;
        public static int numberofb;
        public static String yesn;
        public static int rounds;
        public static int newbank;
        public static String s = ("stuff");

        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));

            //Variables
            bank = file.nextInt();
            goal = file.nextInt();
            beta = file.nextInt();
            prob = file.nextDouble();
            numberofb = 0;
            String yesn = file.next();
            rounds = file.nextInt();
            newbank = bank;


            //Logic
            while(bank > 0 && bank < goal) {

                for(int i = 0; i <= rounds; i++) {

                    bank -= beta;

                    //Win
                    if(Math.random() < prob) {
                        bank += (1/prob) * 1;
                        numberofb += 1;

                    }

                    if(yesn.equals("Y")) {

                        for(int y = 0; y < bank; y++) {

                            System.out.print("*");

                        }

                        System.out.println();

                    }


                }

            }


            //Main Output
            System.out.print("==Gambling Simulation==\n");
            System.out.printf("Starting Bank:       " + bank + "\n");
            System.out.printf("Goal:            250.00\n");
            System.out.printf("Bet Amount:        1.00\n");
            System.out.printf("Probability:        50%%\n");
            System.out.printf("========Results========\n");
            System.out.printf("Number of Bets:%9s", numberofb + numberofb + "\n");
            System.out.printf("End Bank:%14s\n", bank);


        }
    }
```

Comment: Your loops are inverted.  Think: what is it you want to run 100 times?  There may be (probably are) other issues, but this is the main one.

Comment: I want to repeat the whole simulation 100 times, I want to repeat the gambling till hes bankrupt or has 250, 100 times.

Comment: So which loop should be the "outer" one?

Comment: Another comment is that it is possible that the numbers are outside of your range since the condition that cuts the loop is evaluated AFTER the number is modified. Basically if you have 5 dollars and you lose 10, then the conditon runs and it exits the loop but you have -5, not 0. The same with the winnings. If you have 240 and you win 100, you finish the loop with 340.

Answer (score 0):

Add this If condition so the program will come out from your 100 times simulation if it is less or equal to 0 or 250 or above.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= rounds; i++) {

 if(bank < 1 || bank >= goal)
 {
      break;
 }

 bank -= beta;
```

Keep in mind that 100 times simulation might not let the player to lose all the credit or get above 250 because of the probability, so the program need to stay in the while loop until the player hit the goal and exit from the for loop. HTH.